# Joomla Module Positioning

Tags: joomla, module, components, position, joomla2.5

I have a custom component built for a Joomla 2.5 website. It is working fine, except that the modules which display on all pages on the website (logo, global navigation, etc) are pushed under--instead of on top of-- the component.

I've been looking into other components to see what is wrong, to no avail. Would this have to do with the 'views' folder? Perhaps the controller.php?

I also considered wrapping my component in a module, and then setting its position as low as possible as a workaround. Unfortunately, all the extensions I could find for this utility cost more money than I have...

Please help! Thank you :)

Comment: I kinda follow what you're saying ,but not clear on if your modules are having problems, or if your component is.

Comment: Well, the modules seem to display at the top of every other page, just the one with the component messes up the document flow. In firebug, the html generated for the module comes before even the header code.

Comment: Am confused about your use of "module"..."the html generated for the module comes before", don't you mean your custom component?

Comment: There should be exactly one component on a page, and additional modules if desired. The component is the main body of the page, while the modules are things like header items, footer items, sidebars, etc... 

I have only modules which are supposed to display in my template's toolbar (header) area. And yet, the custom component generates html before even these topmost modules.

Comment: I understand Joomla very well, but your problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with the title you gave it in that it's the MVC output that is being done before it should be.  I'd suggest submitting a new question about MVC output in Joomla to get the attention of those experts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you've following the standard MVC framework within Joomla, then with almost 100% certainty your problem will lie in the CSS styles/classes that you're using and how they work with the template stylesheets.  If you're not using Firebug, get that and install it to see what CSS is causing the problem.